# Cross Domain Scripting Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on this 'Random Quote Machine' project.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  getQuote();

  $("#new-quote").on("click", getQuote);

  function getQuote() {
    $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=?", function(a) {
      var quote = "";
      var author = "";
      author = a[0].title;
      quote = a[0].content;
      $(".author").html(author);
      $("#quote").html(quote);
      $("#share-button").attr("href", 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + "\"" + $('#quote > p').html() + "\" - " + author);
    })
  };
});
```

Issues: 
I don't know about Cross Domain Scripting Issue. And the problem I'm facing is that I couldn't get the API's data.So people suggested adding **"&_jsonp"** in the URL. But now even after adding that it only works when my browser sends **'http'** request instead of **'https'** 
When the browser sends https request this message is displayed in my chrom dev console:

**jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codepen.io/faisal1337/full/ZOvgNR/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=jQuery22407926761305727481_1469082997979&_=1469082997982'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.**

So the '&_jsonp' will let a malicious code run on my website. I just want the page to function whether the request is **'http'** or **'https'**. Is there a solution?

Comment: instead of using `http://x.com` or `https://x.com` use `//x.com` ... a http page will use http, a https page will use https - is that what you need?

Comment: Yes exactly. I've changed it. And now it works just fine.The quote loads whether its **http** or **https** preceding the URL. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `http://x.com` or `https://x.com` use `//x.com` ... a http page will use http, a https page will use https

in other words, the page will use the same protocol for requests that the page is loaded with (http vs https)

Answer (score 0):

Use `https` in the ajaxed url if you have a your site on https as well, this is a security measure

```
 $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=?", function(a) {
....
```

demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRrkWB